# Configure width, wrap & font of pop-up

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, joptionpane

I'm Java beginner. I'm using the below code to show a pop-up whenever required in my application.

```
public static int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent,
        Object message, String title, int optionType)
    {
        JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            optionType);
        //pane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 12));//Not working to change the font of pop-up text and button texts
        final JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);
        dialog.setVisible(false) ;
        //dialog.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 12)); //Not working to change the font of pop-up text and button texts
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parentComponent);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.setVisible(true) ;
        dialog.dispose();
        Object o = pane.getValue();
        if (o instanceof Integer) {
            return (Integer)o;
        }
        return JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION;
    }
```

The pop up is being shown properly, but have following problems:

1. How to change the font to the pop up text/message and text of button (yes/no)?
2. How to restrict the pop up width to its parents width?
3. How to wrap the pop up text (like wrapping the text in text area)?

Update: (Answer for 1)
Get the components from JOptionPane and set the fonts as below:

```
private static final String key = "OptionPane.messageFont";

//Question: QUESTION_MESSAGE
public static int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent,
   Object message, String title, int optionType){

    UIManager.put(key, new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 12));
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        optionType);
    JPanel buttonPanel = (JPanel)pane.getComponent(1);
    Object buttonOk[] = buttonPanel.getComponents();
      for (int i = 0; i < buttonOk.length; i++) {
        JButton button = (JButton)buttonOk[i];
            button.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 12));
            button.validate();
      }

    pane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 12));
    final JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);
    dialog.setVisible(false) ;
    dialog.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 12));
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parentComponent);
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setModal(true);
    dialog.setVisible(true) ;
    dialog.dispose();
    Object o = pane.getValue();
    if (o instanceof Integer) {
        return (Integer)o;
    }
    return JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION;
}
```

Update 2 (Answer for 3rd question):

Use the below function which automatically wraps the text. This function inturn calls `showConfirmDialog(parentComponent, message, title, optionType);` The code for  `showConfirmDialog(...)` is already given in the question.

```
/**
     * Question/Confirmation Message Dialog Multiline. 
     * It DONOT require linebreak ("\n") for multiline messages. It will automatically wrap the text to new lines.
     * Note: last when used was not properly working. Please verify it.
     */
    public static int showConfirmDialogMultiLine(Component parentComponent,
               Object message, String title, int optionType){

      JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea((String)message); 

      textArea.setColumns(50);
      textArea.setLineWrap( true );
      textArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
      textArea.setSize(textArea.getPreferredSize().width, 1);
      textArea.setBackground(parentComponent.getBackground());
      textArea.setFont(Usability.getFont("DialogBoxes.DialogTextFont")); //$NON-NLS-1$
      textArea.setEditable(false);
      message = textArea;  
      int retVal = showConfirmDialog(parentComponent,  
              message,  
              title,  
              optionType);  
        return retVal;
    }
```

**Do anybody know answers for 2nd question?**

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `UIManager` to change the `OptionPane.messageFont`, as suggested below.

```
private static final String key = "OptionPane.messageFont";
...
private int showConfirmDialog(...) {
    UIManager.put(key, UIManager.getFont(key).deriveFont(Font.ITALIC, 20));
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(...);
    ...
}
```

Addendum: *Where do I get different keys*?

[*UIManager Defaults*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) is an excellent resource for this, as it can examine the default properties of installed Look & Feel implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. using which I've posted answer for 1 question. where do i get different keys for OptionPane like, `private static final String key = "OptionPane.messageFont";`